# I need to close zoom in zoom out for elementor site for phones

Tags: html, css, animation, zooming, elementor

I was doing my the site  responsive with elementor pro for phones and then i relized that when using an extra widget (vertical picture scrolling) people cant zoom in or zoom out with this animation.(its bassicly similar with scroll snap ).Unfortunately i have some popups on this site.When i open a popup i can zoom in or out with androids and when i close the popup again.The animation will start working again and the site will stuck in this zoomed position.I can only thing that preventing the zooming and zooming out for the phones.Do u guys have any css code that prevents or erase the zoom in zoom out function for elementor site ?

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />` should disable all zooming on devices

Comment: that didnt work. Maybe its because its not working well with wordpress elementor. Do you know how to add an html  code correctly to wordpress ? My wordpress elementor site: startup.aqexperts.de. If you go from phone and try pop up (mehr erfahren button) and zoom You would see it .